# SharedPreference Value is Not Updated

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i started an Activity and a Service from Widget. i use one sharedpreference in both Activity and Service. When i update the preference value from the activity, it is not getting updated in service. Please see the code.

```
SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences("mPrefValue", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String targetValue = myPref.getString("mPrefValue", "0");
System.out.println("targetValue "+targetValue);
```

Comment: is it `myPref` or `preferences` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you access the shared preferences, you call`getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode);`  Just specify `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you forget to commit ?

```
myPref.edit().putString("mPrefValue", "a value").commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please paste a little bit more of code so we can have a better look to your problem.

How have you populated this SharedPreferences? have you used .commit() method (after adding new prefs)  to ensure that your preference has been "uploaded" correctly to the SharedPreferences object?

If so, and you still have this problem, I think using SharedPreferencesListeners could be another solution.
Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html

bye :)